# using java awt robots on browser

Tags: java, oracle, awt, weblogic, awtrobot

Trying to use java awt robots in the deployed application, initially got headless exception 
thought changing headless property will do, but still the issue exists

```
    try {
        Field defaultHeadlessField =      java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.class.getDeclaredField("defaultHeadless");
        defaultHeadlessField.setAccessible(true);
        defaultHeadlessField.set(null,Boolean.FALSE);
        Field headlessField = java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.class.getDeclaredField("headless");
        headlessField.setAccessible(true);
        headlessField.set(null,Boolean.FALSE);
        System.out.print(GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless());
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
```

but now it says

```
java.awt.HeadlessException
at sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice(HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.java:64)
```

basic use case is to simulate keypress(0) on browser window, need some help in solving this issue.

Comment: Is this being sun in a headless environment?  If so, using reflection to change a field will not magically solve that.  If not, I don't understand why the error is being produced.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) & describe the environment this is being run in (e.g. servlet, desktop app., command line app.).

Comment: It is a J2EE application which is deployed on a weblogic server. 
when the piece of code related to robot is executed where does it run on server side or client ??

Comment: If it is being run from a J2EE application, it is run on the server.

Comment: so is there any alternative to achieve a keypress ??

Comment: From the server, in the user's browser? I hope not.  It seems it would be a huge security hole.  What is the actual point of all this anyway?